# What is the equivalent of TFS 2008 "coreGet" in TFS 2010 team build workflow?

Tags: msbuild, workflow

Just would like to know the equivalent of TFS 2008 coreGet in TFS 2010 team build workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the standard workflow in Visual studio and you can very easily see how Microsoft has done it. I assume you're looking for the [Get Workspace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.workflow.activities.getworkspace.aspx) action or the [Download Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.workflow.activities.downloadfiles.aspx) action.